# REST API Schema: how to allows for both empty string or email string

Tags: rest-api

I’m extending a REST endpoint with register_rest_field();

The field I’m registering should accept an email address or an empty string.

I’m using the `JSONschema` to check and validate the format, like the below code:

```
register_rest_field(
    'my_custom_post', 
    'my_email_field', 
    array(
        'schema' => array(
        'type' => array('string','null'),
            'format' => 'email',
        'description' => 'Email address to use for contact',
        'context' => array('view','edit','embed'),
         ),
     'get_callback' => 'myemail_custom_get_callback',
     'update_callback' => 'myemail_custom_update_callback'
     )
);
```

The issue I have is that even if I put in the schema `'type' => array('string','null')` I can’t POST a request with this field left empty, because WP always respond with `rest_invalid_param` and `rest_invalid_email` .

Only if I remove the`'format' => 'email'` argument, WP accepts both an empty field or a string as expected, but this way I can’t check if it’s a valid email anymore.

By reading here https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/schema/#format (especially the last example in that paragraph) I can’t see whats wrong with my schema. Could it be a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> even if I put in the schema `'type' => array('string','null')` I can’t
> POST a request with this field left empty, because WP always respond
> with `rest_invalid_param` and `rest_invalid_email`

Actually, adding the `'null'` there does not mean that any empty-ish values like `''` and `0` will be allowed. It just means that an actual `null` value is allowed, apart from string. E.g. (these are JSON-encoded data)

- `{"my_email_field":"foo@bar.com"}` ✅
- `{"my_email_field":null}` ✅
- `{"my_email_field":""}` ❌ (value is empty, but it's not a null)
- `{"my_email_field":"null"}` ❌ (invalid email address..)

So if you had sent a `null`, you would have not received those errors.

But then, a `null` will unfortunately not pass the `isset( $request[ $field_name ] )` validation in [`WP_REST_Controller::update_additional_fields_for_object()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_controller/update_additional_fields_for_object/), hence the update callback will *never be called*. <sub>[(See source on GitHub)](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.4/src/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-controller.php#L463-L466)</sub>

- So maybe the WordPress core team should do something about that.. e.g. use `array_key_exists()` instead..

But as stated in @birgire's answer, you can use the **`anyOf` or `oneOf`** property to achieve what you were trying to do. <sub>[(See source on GitHub)](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.4/src/wp-includes/rest-api.php#L2120-L2140)</sub>

Here's an example which requires the value to be an empty string where the length is exactly 0, *or* a non-empty string which must be a properly-formatted email address:

```php
'schema' => array(
    'type'        => 'string',
    'oneOf'       => array(
        // Requires an empty string.
        array(
            'type'      => 'string',
            'maxLength' => 0,
        ),
        // Or if it's not empty, then it must be a valid email address.
        array(
            'type'   => 'string',
            'format' => 'email',
        ),
    ),
    'description' => 'Email address to use for contact',
    // Your other args.
),
```

Another one that you might want to try is, a **custom validate callback** which can be passed via `arg_options.validate_callback` like so:

- Supplying the custom validate callback:

  ```php
  'schema'          => array(
      'type'        => 'string',
      'arg_options' => array(
          'validate_callback' => 'myemail_custom_validate_callback',
      ),
      'description' => 'Email address to use for contact',
      // Your other args.
  ),
  ```
- Sample callback:

  ```php
  function myemail_custom_validate_callback( $value, $request, $param ) {
      // Requires an empty string or a valid email address.
      if ( 0 === strlen( $value ) || is_email( $value ) ) {
          return true;
      }

      return new WP_Error(
          'rest_invalid_param',
          sprintf( '%s is not a valid email address', $param )
      );
  }
  ```

<sub>**Note:** Specifying a custom validate callback means the default/core ones (e.g. [`rest_validate_value_from_schema()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_validate_value_from_schema/)) would no longer be used, unless explicitly called from within your callback.</sub>

Comment: Great, thanks for checking it in source, as I wrote my answer on mobile I trusted the line I stumbled up on in the linked docs,   mentioning "If allowing an “empty” value is desired, add null as a possible type." :-)

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too, but the quotes as in `"empty"` made me curious (that urged me to check the source) and think that maybe what they meant was that a `null` will not throw the errors in question? Or maybe, in the past, `null` would still be accepted in that the field's update callback would be called.

Comment: yes, I remember I thought by the quote it could behave like the  empty() function validation.

Comment: @birgire yep, I had the same thought, until I tried the code in question. Hence, I checked the source when I realized nothing was being updated. :)

Comment: @brigire @sally-cj thank you for yours helpful answer. My current implementation relies on **custom validate callback** but I would like to streamline my code transitioning that validation to the `schema`. I had not thought to the use of `oneOf` that indeed looks like a valid solution. In the meantime a come up with another possible solution:  it involved specifying `null` on both `format` and `type`. I'll post it as another aswer, do you mind looking at it and tell me what you think about it?

Comment: My solution that involves using `null` on both `format` and `type` is not working as intended: it bypass the validations altogether so it accepets invalid emails too. Looks like the way to go is the use of `oneOf`

Comment: @Stefano, either `oneOf` or `anyOf` would work in your case since it's impossible for both conditions (in my example) to be met at the same time. And remember that, (for now) sending a `null` will not update the existing value because [`! isset( $request['your_field'] )` will be `true` when `your_field` is a `null`](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.4/src/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-controller.php#L463-L466), hence the update callback is not gonna be called. :/

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `is_email()` will return `false` for input less than 6 chars according to [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_email/). Try instead for example `anyOf` or `oneOf` in the schema to separate the null type and the `is_email` check: (untested)

```
array(
    'schema' => array(
        'anyOf' => array(
            array(
                'type'   => 'string',
                'format' => 'email',
                …etc
            ),
            array(
                'type' => 'null',
                …etc
            ),
          ),
       ),
    ),
),
```